# Django forms checkbox required even if require:false in form attrs

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

how can i make my checkbox not required using django forms?

**my forms.py**

```py
invoice = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class':'checkboxInvoice','required': 'False'}))
```

**my models.py**

```py
invoice  = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings this in the attrs is *not* sufficient, you should specify this at the form field level:

```
invoice = forms.BooleanField(
    widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class':'checkboxInvoice'}),
    required=False
)
```

If you are only overriding the widget, it might be better to simply alter the widgets:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['invoice']
        widgets = {
            'invoice': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class':'checkboxInvoice'})
        }
```